# Parameters array in Angular UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngtable

I am using ngTable that use filters in the format `filter[foo]`, `filter[bar]`, `sorting[foo]`, `sorting[bar]`.
I want to pass this parameters as URL, but as I am using UI Router, I need to declare them in the state definition.
So I tried to setup a state like this

```
  .state('admin.results', {
    url: '/results?filter[foo]',
    templateUrl: 'app/results.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ResultCtrl'
  })
```

but the square brackets look to be interpreted as a regex, so I get an error like this

```
Invalid parameter name 'filter[foo]' in pattern '/results?filter[foo]'
```

I also tried escaping the brackets `url: '/results?filter\[foo\]'` but again I receive the same error.
You can try it in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aCjLXczmadMIHv9TFxd7?p=preview).

Comment: Was looking solution for this issue too. Any luck?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$routeProvider.when('/results/:filter', {
  controller: 'typeFormController',
  templateUrl: 'app/results.tpl.html'
});
```

And in your controller use `$routeParams.filter` to get your filter

Comment: Thanks, but I need filter to be a query parameter, not a url parameter. I don't think this would accept `/results?filter[foo]`.